# Don't understand how to use ${PORT}

Tags: javascript, express

I am watching a tutorial where when the guy inputs this:

```
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server beating  on PORT ${PORT}'); 
})
```

he gets "Server beating <3 on PORT 3001"

for me when I use that same code, the ${ } doesn't do anything. Should I be using something else? Is it because I'm not using linux?

Comment: you have to use template tags,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals for further read

Answer (score 2):

Try using `backticks` instead of `single quotes` like so:

```js
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server beating  on PORT ${PORT}`); 
})
```

PS. backtick symbol lives above the `tab` key on your keyboard

Comment: Yes you were right! Thank you so much! Had to reload the page!